# Using mathf.Repeat and specify the start time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

basicly in my project i have a plane that i want to do a specific movement from position **a** to **b** every time, when he reaches **b** he go back to **a** again.

**So i did this:**

```
public class pingPongPlane : MonoBehaviour {

    public float MinX = -10.2f; // y position of start point
    public float MaxX = 55f; // y position of end point
    public float PingPongTime = 1f; // how much time to wait before reverse
    public Rigidbody rb; // reference to the rigidbody

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine( ShowEvent() ) ;
    }

    IEnumerator ShowEvent(){
        while (true) {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (4f);
            //get a value between 0 and 1
            float normalizedTime = Mathf.Repeat (Time.time, PingPongTime) / PingPongTime;
            //then multiply it by the delta between start and end point, and add start point to the result
            float xPosition = normalizedTime * (MaxX - MinX) + MinX;
            //finally update position using rigidbody 
            rb.MovePosition (new Vector3 (xPosition, rb.position.y, rb.position.z));
        }
    }
}
```

with updated and without the curoutine i had the movement i wanted, but my plane should wait 5 seconds on **a -> begin position** before moving, and i didn't remeber other solution then curoutine, using curoutine with the following code, the movement is not smooth, is kinda strange it just goes from 1 position to another it doesn't seem like a movement.

Answer (score 0):

you can do your movement in `Update` but stop it for a few seconds with an `if` statement and a `yield` that waits the amount of time needed

```
public bool CanStart = false;

 void Start ()
 {
     StartCoroutine (StartMove());
 }

 void Update ()
 {
     if (CanStart == true)
     {
           //get a value between 0 and 1
            float normalizedTime = Mathf.Repeat (Time.time, PingPongTime) / PingPongTime;
            //then multiply it by the delta between start and end point, and add start point to the result
            float xPosition = normalizedTime * (MaxX - MinX) + MinX;
            //finally update position using rigidbody 
            rb.MovePosition (new Vector3 (xPosition, rb.position.y, rb.position.z))

     }

 }

 IEnumerator StartMove()
 {
     yield return new WaitForSeconds (5.0f);
     CanStart = true;
 }
```

Comment: not working, i dont want to move the object, i want to shrink till it dissapears, that moves the object